# How correctly use WhenEvent to detect when gradient is over a certain value?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

So I wish to stop integrating my PDE when the spatial gradient is larger than some value, let's say 10. That is to say, my WhenEvent condition wants to be stop when the the maximum gradient over all x at a given t exceeds a threshold.

However, when I try implement the code I get "The function value is not True or False errors".

Here's my attempt:

```
NDSolve[{Derivative[0, 1][h][x, t] + 2000 h[x, t]*Derivative[1, 0][h][x, t] == 
  1/4 D[(1 - 4 h[x, t]^2)^3 Derivative[1, 0][h][x, t], x], 
  h[-1/2, t] == 0, h[1/2, t] == 0, h[x, 0] == 0.1 Sin[8 π (x - 1/2)], 
  WhenEvent[NMaximize[Derivative[1, 0][h][x, t]] > 10, tEnd = t; 
  "StopIntegration"]}, h[x, t], {x, -1/2, 1/2}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "DiscretizedMonitorVariables" -> True, 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 100000}}];
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why `Max[ ]` .. ?

Comment: I want to know the time at when the gradient goes over 10 anywhere

Comment: Not sure why to use Table?

Comment: is the idea to reject the entire solution in the event it has a large gradient?  I think you need to compute the solution then analyze it.

Comment: Tried amending code to use NMaximise. It returns an error: "The function value is not a number at {x}..."

Comment: Idea is to stop integration before a shock/singularity develops. I want to know time of shock development, so when gradient passes some large threshold anywhere

Comment: I see. Your condition wants to be stop when the the maximum gradient over all *x* at a given *t* exceeds a threshold. (You might want to expalin that in some words in the question ). I suspect this is beyond the capability of `WhenEvent`, and you should just crunch out the solution and find the critical time in post processing.   Do you perhaps want the `Max` `Abs` by the way?

Comment: The error message described in the question occurs because "DiscretizedMonitorVariables" -> True causes `NDSolve` to treat `[Derivative[1, 0][h][x, t]]` in `WhenEvent` as a `List` before `Derivative` is carried out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After playing with this a bit: it seems `WhenEvent[ h[x,t] ]` gets passed the list of discrete x-grid values at each time step. So we can numerically compute the gradient:

```
rr = Reap[
   sol = NDSolve[{...,
      WhenEvent[
       Sow[Max[Abs[Subtract @@@ Partition[ h[x, t] , 2, 1]]] 100000] > 10, 
       "StopIntegration"]},
     h[x, t], {x, -1/2, 1/2}, {t, 0, 10},
     Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "DiscretizedMonitorVariables" -> True, 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "MinPoints" -> 100000}}]];
 f = h[x, t] /. First@sol;
```

note I assume uniform grid spacing which in this case is set by your specified minpoints (But that's not guaranteed).   You can verify that by looking at the interpolation function grid.

The critical time:

```
tmax = f[[0]]["Domain"][[2, 2]]
```

> 0.000172062

```
Plot3D[f, {x, -1/2, 1/2}, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image]

here is the derivative and you can see it becoming unstable..

```
g = D[f, x];
Plot3D[g, {x, -1/2, 1/2}, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]
```

[image]

here is the max gradient value captured by `Reap/Sow`

```
ListPlot[rr[[2, 1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. This works brilliantly!